# Facebook ads not showing in only samsung devices. Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, facebook-audience-network, samsung

I have implemented facebook ads in flutter using facebook_audience_network package. I have completed all the steps as mention in documentation. ads showing fine in other android devices only not showing in samsung devices. please help me out if anyone help solution for this problem

https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network use for ads package

Comment: Is there any error or warning on the logcat?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.